# The colors in my THREE.JS project are messed up after the update

Tags: three.js, fbx, color-space, gamma

The colors in my project (which use fbx models) are messed up, after updating to version 136. The colors are much darker now. The [migration guide](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide) stated:

> `WebGLRenderer.gammaFactor` and `THREE.GammaEncoding` have been removed.
> Please use post processing (a gamma correction pass) if you need a
> special gamma color space.

But I have no idea on how to "use post processing (a gamma correction pass)". I would be very thankful if someone give me a simple example on how to fix it.

Comment: I recommend asking this question on the [three.js discourse site](https://discourse.threejs.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to set the outputEncoding of your renderer and the encoding of your materials like this:

```
material.emissiveMap.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
```

(or in a different encoding according to the desired result)
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/constants/Textures
(see the endoding section)